# C# smtp gmail not working on server, but working well in localhost

Tags: c#, dns, smtp, vps

My application have function to sent email trough smtp.gmail.com

It works well when i run at local, but after i publish to vps, the email not sent.

dns setting for mx(10) was pointing to smtp.gmail.com
[image: dns setting for mx(10) was pointing to smtp.gmail.com]

here's the code that i use :

```
public ServiceResult SendEmailOrder(string Email)
    {
        ServiceResult result = new ServiceResult();
        try
        {
            const string fromPassword = "password";

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();

            mail.From = new MailAddress("senderaddress@gmail.com");
            mail.Subject = "subject mail";
            mail.Body = "Body Mail";

            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("senderaddress@gmail.com", fromPassword);
            SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;


            mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(Email));
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result.Error("Failed Send Email", ex.InnerException.Message);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

is that something that i missing?

*note : 
- my vps was connect to internet,
- i use google cloud before, and the code works well.

Comment: Did you checked "SMTP" port on firewall?

Comment: @xwpedram .. i'm not too understand about that. how to do that?